# How to get endOf day toISOString() in momentjs but the milliseconds should be .000Z and not .999Z

Tags: reactjs, angular, react-native, vue.js, momentjs

Basically I have a date:

```
const now = moment()
console.log(now.endOf('day').toISOString()) // 2021-10-25T21:59:59.999Z
```

**I would like to have it as : 2021-10-25T21:59:59.000Z**

As a walkaround I did

```
console.log(`${moment().endOf('day').utc().format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss')}.000Z`)
```

and got my desired printout, but

**MAYBE SOMEONE HAS a more elegant way?**

Thanks people!

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively, you could convert the `moment` to a `Date` (or just use `Date` itself), and use [`Date.prototype.setUTCHours()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setUTCHours) with `0` as the 4th argument (for milliseconds):

```js
const now = new Date()
now.setUTCHours(23,59,59,0) // end of day
console.log(now.toISOString())
```